# How to read and turn a 13Gbite text in python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, text, dataset

I have a 1.5Gbite rar file that when I open it it gives me 13 Gbite .txt file and I can't load it with anything. I used:

```
import pandas as pd
read_file = pd.read_csv (r'Path where the Text file is stored\File name.txt', sep='\t')
read_file.to_csv (r'Path where the CSV will be saved\File name.csv', index=None)
```

I used it in Pycharm and it takes forever and gives

> MemoryError

I used colab in it crashed and I think it's because my Drive was almost full because I only have 15G of drive.
What should I do?

Comment: https://intellipaat.com/community/5392/python-fastest-way-to-read-a-large-text-file-several-gb

Comment: NameError: name 'process_lines' is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chunksize parameter specifies the number of rows per chunk.

```
chunksize = 10 ** 6
with pd.read_csv(filename, chunksize=chunksize, on_bad_lines='skip') as reader:
    for chunk in reader:
        # you can use chunk to process the data in parts
```

Comment: I write after for: print(chunk) and it says: pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 933, saw 35

Comment: can you print the error trace please

Comment: Try with my new answer, let me know what u get

Comment: now how can I turn it into csv? so I can access columns?

Comment: your data is present as dataframe, you can access the column directly as ['column name']

Comment: I get this error when I want to access url: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1khl_FE7XGTjiPCRQYaFKNdWhF3zUzCUd/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you show me the head of your datfra,me

Comment: for first chunk it's this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/18lJ07CAV8dWWGzADZ2gAsjWlrxB-0R2U/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I see that each of your row is present as a dict, can you please use `pd.read_dict` to  read the data

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1azWzSIUO5EIzyRe9YLpqEwDmD741M3Lt/view?usp=sharing

Comment: sorry if I was not clear, your data is not in a csv format, you ll have to first read the dat as json and then add the dict to pandas datframe

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: I emailed the link